# Unable to force Okta Auth0's AuthGuard to redirect to some route after successful login when user initially asks for a protected route

Tags: angular, oauth, auth0, okta

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com) in my Angular application to authentify users as described below :

1. User comes on root page (eg: https://my-app.com) and click on Login button via Google account
2. User gets redirected to Auth0 login page via Google form
3. User types his Google's account credentials in the form and connected successfully
4. User is redirected to https://my-app.com/auth that falls on `auth-component` which is responsible for checking wether user is already in the database so he'll be redirected to `/main` or should be redirected to another page `/profile` to save his credentials.

So my routing module looks almost like this :

```
import {AuthGuard} from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: "/",
   redirectTo: "/login"
  },
  {
   path: "/login",
   component: "LoginComponent"
  },
  {
   path: "/auth",
   component: "AuthComponent",
   canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
   path: "/profile",
   component: "ProfileComponent",
   canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
   path: "/main",
   component: "MainComponent",
   canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
]
```

Now my issue is that when I'm on the root (https://my-app.com/) and try to access directly from address-bar the url `/main`, I get redirected to the login via Google form as wanted and once authentication is successful I get redirected automatically to `/main` without passing by `/auth` despite that I only have https://my-app.com/auth as `Allowed Callback URLs` in Auth0 configuration panel.

I should be missing some parameter that force returning to `/auth` after trying to access a protected route by Auth0 `AuthGuard`.

After some researches, I found a [resource](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/angular/basic-authentication#add-route-guards-to-angular) saying that this can be achieved by setting `appState.target` to the wanted route but I was not able to find how to do so !

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and after some research I've found that this setting was missing in my app.module.ts:

AuthModule.forRoot({
...
**authorizationParams: {
redirect_uri: window.location.origin
}**
...
})